# aframe-react; writing new component error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, aframe, aframe-react

I'm not really sure what I'm screwing up here. I've managed to write my own components in basic A-Frame but since moving to aframe-react I'm getting the error:

```
Error in ./src/components.js

C:\PATH_TO\src\components.js
  1:1  error  'AFRAME' is not defined  no-undef
```

components.js:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('pointer_click', {
    // ...
});
```

Am I importing it wrong?

```
import 'aframe';
import 'aframe-animation-component';
import 'aframe-particle-system-component';
import 'babel-polyfill';
import {Entity, Scene} from 'aframe-react';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './components.js';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using create-react-app, then you need to follow this [create-react-app-global-vars](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/react-scripts/template/README.md#using-global-variables) to reference 'AFRAME' as a global variable.

Basically, include this at the top of your AFrame component file.

```
const AFRAME = window.AFRAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps that's just a lint error or bundler error? What bundler are you using? I wonder if you have to declare `AFRAME` as a global somewhere (e.g., `/* globals AFRAME */` at the top) or define `AFRAME` as a global in some config.

If you are possibly using `semistandard` linter, you can put in package.json:

```
"semistandard": {
  "globals": [
    "AFRAME",
    "THREE"
  ],
  "ignore": [
    "build/**"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you mean, I'm totally new to React and working off the aframe-react boilerplate. I assumed I could just import a regular JavaScript file with my components in?

That's what was working with vanilla A-Frame?

Comment: Only just looking at bundlers etc now, up until now I've been working off localhost using npm